# Upgrade 5.2.2 to 5.10.4 fails with UPDATE civicrm_msg_template error

Tags: upgrade

Wordpress 5.1

This is similar to [Upgrade script (5.0.1 to 5.4.1) / DB Syntax error - UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_text](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26334/upgrade-script-5-0-1-to-5-4-1-db-syntax-error-update-civicrm-msg-template)
for which I don't understand the solution - if in fact one was provided.

Mine refers to contribution invoice receipt which I did have a custom version but I reverted to default before trying to upgrade. Is there perhaps somewhere else I need to delete the custom versions?

Database Error Code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, 1064
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => 
      UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_text = '{assign var=\"greeting\" value=\"{contact.email_greeting}\"}{if $greeting}{$greeting},{/if}\n{if $receipt_text}\n{$receipt_text}\n{/if}\n{if $is_pay_later}\n\n===========================================================\n{$pay_later_receipt}\n===========================================================\n{else}\n\n{ts}Please print this receipt for your records.{/ts}\n{/if}\n\n{if $amount}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Contribution Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{if $lineItem and $priceSetID and !$is_quick_config}\n{foreach from=$lineItem item=value key=priceset}\n---------------------------------------------------------\n{capture assign=ts_item}{ts}Item{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_qty}{ts}Qty{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_each}{ts}Each{/ts}{/capture}\n{if $dataArray}\n{capture assign=ts_subtotal}{ts}Subtotal{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_taxRate}{ts}Tax Rate{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_taxAmount}{ts}Tax Amount{/ts}{/capture}\n{/if}\n{capture assign=ts_total}{ts}Total{/ts}{/capture}\n{$ts_item|string_format:\"%-30s\"} {$ts_qty|string_format:\"%5s\"} {$ts_each|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $dataArray} {$ts_subtotal|string_format:\"%10s\"} {$ts_taxRate} {$ts_taxAmount|string_format:\"%10s\"} {/if} {$ts_total|string_format:\"%10s\"}\n----------------------------------------------------------\n{foreach from=$value item=line}\n{capture assign=ts_item}{if $line.html_type eq \'Text\'}{$line.label}{else}{$line.field_title} - {$line.label}{/if} {if $line.description} {$line.description}{/if}{/capture}{$ts_item|truncate:30:\"...\"|string_format:\"%-30s\"} {$line.qty|string_format:\"%5s\"} {$line.unit_price|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $dataArray}{$line.unit_price*$line.qty|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $line.tax_rate != \"\" || $line.tax_amount != \"\"}  {$line.tax_rate|string_format:\"%.2f\"} %  {$line.tax_amount|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"} {else}                  {/if}  {/if} {$line.line_total+$line.tax_amount|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"}\n{/foreach}\n{/foreach}\n\n{if $dataArray}\n{ts}Amount before Tax{/ts}: {$amount-$totalTaxAmount|crmMoney:$currency}\n\n{foreach from=$dataArray item=value key=priceset}\n{if $priceset || $priceset == 0}\n{$taxTerm} {$priceset|string_format:\"%.2f\"}%: {$value|crmMoney:$currency}\n{else}\n{ts}No{/ts} {$taxTerm}: {$value|crmMoney:$currency}\n{/if}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n\n{if $totalTaxAmount}\n{ts}Total Tax Amount{/ts}: {$totalTaxAmount|crmMoney:$currency}\n{/if}\n\n{ts}Total Amount{/ts}: {$amount|crmMoney:$currency}\n{else}\n{ts}Amount{/ts}: {$amount|crmMoney:$currency} {if $amount_level } - {$amount_level} {/if}\n{/if}\n{/if}\n{if $receive_date}\n\n{ts}Date{/ts}: {$receive_date|crmDate}\n{/if}\n{if $is_monetary and $trxn_id}\n{ts}Transaction #{/ts}: {$trxn_id}\n{/if}\n\n{if $is_recur}\n{ts}This is a recurring contribution.{/ts}\n\n{if $cancelSubscriptionUrl}\n{ts}You can cancel future contributions at:{/ts}\n\n{$cancelSubscriptionUrl}\n\n{/if}\n\n{if $updateSubscriptionBillingUrl}\n{ts}You can update billing details for this recurring contribution at:{/ts}\n\n{$updateSubscriptionBillingUrl}\n\n{/if}\n\n{if $updateSubscriptionUrl}\n{ts}You can update recurring contribution amount or change the number of installments for this recurring contribution at:{/ts}\n\n{$updateSubscriptionUrl}\n\n{/if}\n{/if}\n\n{if $honor_block_is_active}\n===========================================================\n{$soft_credit_type}\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$honoreeProfile item=value key=label}\n{$label}: {$value}\n{/foreach}\n{elseif $softCreditTypes and $softCredits}\n{foreach from=$softCreditTypes item=softCreditType key=n}\n===========================================================\n{$softCreditType}\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$softCredits.$n item=value key=label}\n{$label}: {$value}\n{/foreach}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n{if $pcpBlock}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Personal Campaign Page{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{ts}Display In Honor Roll{/ts}: {if $pcp_display_in_roll}{ts}Yes{/ts}{else}{ts}No{/ts}{/if}\n\n{if $pcp_roll_nickname}{ts}Nickname{/ts}: {$pcp_roll_nickname}{/if}\n\n{if $pcp_personal_note}{ts}Personal Note{/ts}: {$pcp_personal_note}{/if}\n\n{/if}\n{if $onBehalfProfile}\n===========================================================\n{ts}On Behalf Of{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$onBehalfProfile item=onBehalfValue key=onBehalfName}\n{$onBehalfName}: {$onBehalfValue}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n\n{if !( $contributeMode eq \'notify\' OR $contributeMode eq \'directIPN\' ) and $is_monetary}\n{if $is_pay_later && !$isBillingAddressRequiredForPayLater}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Registered Email{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$email}\n{elseif $amount GT 0}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Billing Name and Address{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$billingName}\n{$address}\n\n{$email}\n{/if} {* End ! is_pay_later condition. *}\n{/if}\n{if $contributeMode eq \'direct\' AND !$is_pay_later AND $amount GT 0}\n\n===========================================================\n{ts}Credit Card Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$credit_card_type}\n{$credit_card_number}\n{ts}Expires{/ts}: {$credit_card_exp_date|truncate:7:\'\'|crmDate}\n{/if}\n\n{if $selectPremium }\n===========================================================\n{ts}Premium Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$product_name}\n{if $option}\n{ts}Option{/ts}: {$option}\n{/if}\n{if $sku}\n{ts}SKU{/ts}: {$sku}\n{/if}\n{if $start_date}\n{ts}Start Date{/ts}: {$start_date|crmDate}\n{/if}\n{if $end_date}\n{ts}End Date{/ts}: {$end_date|crmDate}\n{/if}\n{if $contact_email OR $contact_phone}\n\n{ts}For information about this premium, contact:{/ts}\n\n{if $contact_email}\n  {$contact_email}\n{/if}\n{if $contact_phone}\n  {$contact_phone}\n{/if}\n{/if}\n{if $is_deductible AND $price}\n\n{ts 1=$price|crmMoney:$currency}The value of this premium is %1. This may affect the amount of the tax deduction you can claim. Consult your tax advisor for more information.{/ts}{/if}\n{/if}\n\n{if $customPre}\n===========================================================\n{$customPre_grouptitle}\n\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$customPre item=customValue key=customName}\n{if ( $trackingFields and ! in_array( $customName, $trackingFields ) ) or ! $trackingFields}\n {$customName}: {$customValue}\n{/if}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n\n\n{if $customPost}\n===========================================================\n{$customPost_grouptitle}\n\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$customPost item=customValue key=customName}\n{if ( $trackingFields and ! in_array( $customName, $trackingFields ) ) or ! $trackingFields}\n {$customName}: {$customValue}\n{/if}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n' WHERE id IN () [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => 
      UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_text = '{assign var=\"greeting\" value=\"{contact.email_greeting}\"}{if $greeting}{$greeting},{/if}\n{if $receipt_text}\n{$receipt_text}\n{/if}\n{if $is_pay_later}\n\n===========================================================\n{$pay_later_receipt}\n===========================================================\n{else}\n\n{ts}Please print this receipt for your records.{/ts}\n{/if}\n\n{if $amount}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Contribution Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{if $lineItem and $priceSetID and !$is_quick_config}\n{foreach from=$lineItem item=value key=priceset}\n---------------------------------------------------------\n{capture assign=ts_item}{ts}Item{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_qty}{ts}Qty{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_each}{ts}Each{/ts}{/capture}\n{if $dataArray}\n{capture assign=ts_subtotal}{ts}Subtotal{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_taxRate}{ts}Tax Rate{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_taxAmount}{ts}Tax Amount{/ts}{/capture}\n{/if}\n{capture assign=ts_total}{ts}Total{/ts}{/capture}\n{$ts_item|string_format:\"%-30s\"} {$ts_qty|string_format:\"%5s\"} {$ts_each|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $dataArray} {$ts_subtotal|string_format:\"%10s\"} {$ts_taxRate} {$ts_taxAmount|string_format:\"%10s\"} {/if} {$ts_total|string_format:\"%10s\"}\n----------------------------------------------------------\n{foreach from=$value item=line}\n{capture assign=ts_item}{if $line.html_type eq \'Text\'}{$line.label}{else}{$line.field_title} - {$line.label}{/if} {if $line.description} {$line.description}{/if}{/capture}{$ts_item|truncate:30:\"...\"|string_format:\"%-30s\"} {$line.qty|string_format:\"%5s\"} {$line.unit_price|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $dataArray}{$line.unit_price*$line.qty|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $line.tax_rate != \"\" || $line.tax_amount != \"\"}  {$line.tax_rate|string_format:\"%.2f\"} %  {$line.tax_amount|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"} {else}                  {/if}  {/if} {$line.line_total+$line.tax_amount|crmMoney:$currency|string_format:\"%10s\"}\n{/foreach}\n{/foreach}\n\n{if $dataArray}\n{ts}Amount before Tax{/ts}: {$amount-$totalTaxAmount|crmMoney:$currency}\n\n{foreach from=$dataArray item=value key=priceset}\n{if $priceset || $priceset == 0}\n{$taxTerm} {$priceset|string_format:\"%.2f\"}%: {$value|crmMoney:$currency}\n{else}\n{ts}No{/ts} {$taxTerm}: {$value|crmMoney:$currency}\n{/if}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n\n{if $totalTaxAmount}\n{ts}Total Tax Amount{/ts}: {$totalTaxAmount|crmMoney:$currency}\n{/if}\n\n{ts}Total Amount{/ts}: {$amount|crmMoney:$currency}\n{else}\n{ts}Amount{/ts}: {$amount|crmMoney:$currency} {if $amount_level } - {$amount_level} {/if}\n{/if}\n{/if}\n{if $receive_date}\n\n{ts}Date{/ts}: {$receive_date|crmDate}\n{/if}\n{if $is_monetary and $trxn_id}\n{ts}Transaction #{/ts}: {$trxn_id}\n{/if}\n\n{if $is_recur}\n{ts}This is a recurring contribution.{/ts}\n\n{if $cancelSubscriptionUrl}\n{ts}You can cancel future contributions at:{/ts}\n\n{$cancelSubscriptionUrl}\n\n{/if}\n\n{if $updateSubscriptionBillingUrl}\n{ts}You can update billing details for this recurring contribution at:{/ts}\n\n{$updateSubscriptionBillingUrl}\n\n{/if}\n\n{if $updateSubscriptionUrl}\n{ts}You can update recurring contribution amount or change the number of installments for this recurring contribution at:{/ts}\n\n{$updateSubscriptionUrl}\n\n{/if}\n{/if}\n\n{if $honor_block_is_active}\n===========================================================\n{$soft_credit_type}\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$honoreeProfile item=value key=label}\n{$label}: {$value}\n{/foreach}\n{elseif $softCreditTypes and $softCredits}\n{foreach from=$softCreditTypes item=softCreditType key=n}\n===========================================================\n{$softCreditType}\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$softCredits.$n item=value key=label}\n{$label}: {$value}\n{/foreach}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n{if $pcpBlock}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Personal Campaign Page{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{ts}Display In Honor Roll{/ts}: {if $pcp_display_in_roll}{ts}Yes{/ts}{else}{ts}No{/ts}{/if}\n\n{if $pcp_roll_nickname}{ts}Nickname{/ts}: {$pcp_roll_nickname}{/if}\n\n{if $pcp_personal_note}{ts}Personal Note{/ts}: {$pcp_personal_note}{/if}\n\n{/if}\n{if $onBehalfProfile}\n===========================================================\n{ts}On Behalf Of{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$onBehalfProfile item=onBehalfValue key=onBehalfName}\n{$onBehalfName}: {$onBehalfValue}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n\n{if !( $contributeMode eq \'notify\' OR $contributeMode eq \'directIPN\' ) and $is_monetary}\n{if $is_pay_later && !$isBillingAddressRequiredForPayLater}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Registered Email{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$email}\n{elseif $amount GT 0}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Billing Name and Address{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$billingName}\n{$address}\n\n{$email}\n{/if} {* End ! is_pay_later condition. *}\n{/if}\n{if $contributeMode eq \'direct\' AND !$is_pay_later AND $amount GT 0}\n\n===========================================================\n{ts}Credit Card Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$credit_card_type}\n{$credit_card_number}\n{ts}Expires{/ts}: {$credit_card_exp_date|truncate:7:\'\'|crmDate}\n{/if}\n\n{if $selectPremium }\n===========================================================\n{ts}Premium Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{$product_name}\n{if $option}\n{ts}Option{/ts}: {$option}\n{/if}\n{if $sku}\n{ts}SKU{/ts}: {$sku}\n{/if}\n{if $start_date}\n{ts}Start Date{/ts}: {$start_date|crmDate}\n{/if}\n{if $end_date}\n{ts}End Date{/ts}: {$end_date|crmDate}\n{/if}\n{if $contact_email OR $contact_phone}\n\n{ts}For information about this premium, contact:{/ts}\n\n{if $contact_email}\n  {$contact_email}\n{/if}\n{if $contact_phone}\n  {$contact_phone}\n{/if}\n{/if}\n{if $is_deductible AND $price}\n\n{ts 1=$price|crmMoney:$currency}The value of this premium is %1. This may affect the amount of the tax deduction you can claim. Consult your tax advisor for more information.{/ts}{/if}\n{/if}\n\n{if $customPre}\n===========================================================\n{$customPre_grouptitle}\n\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$customPre item=customValue key=customName}\n{if ( $trackingFields and ! in_array( $customName, $trackingFields ) ) or ! $trackingFields}\n {$customName}: {$customValue}\n{/if}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n\n\n{if $customPost}\n===========================================================\n{$customPost_grouptitle}\n\n===========================================================\n{foreach from=$customPost item=customValue key=customName}\n{if ( $trackingFields and ! in_array( $customName, $trackingFields ) ) or ! $trackingFields}\n {$customName}: {$customValue}\n{/if}\n{/foreach}\n{/if}\n' WHERE id IN () [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
      UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_text = '{assign var=\"greeting\" value=\"{contact.email_greeting}\"}{if $greeting}{$greeting},{/if}\n{if $receipt_text}\n{$receipt_text}\n{/if}\n{if $is_pay_later}\n\n===========================================================\n{$pay_later_receipt}\n===========================================================\n{else}\n\n{ts}Please print this receipt for your records.{/ts}\n{/if}\n\n{if $amount}\n===========================================================\n{ts}Contribution Information{/ts}\n\n===========================================================\n{if $lineItem and $priceSetID and !$is_quick_config}\n{foreach from=$lineItem item=value key=priceset}\n---------------------------------------------------------\n{capture assign=ts_item}{ts}Item{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_qty}{ts}Qty{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_each}{ts}Each{/ts}{/capture}\n{if $dataArray}\n{capture assign=ts_subtotal}{ts}Subtotal{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_taxRate}{ts}Tax Rate{/ts}{/capture}\n{capture assign=ts_taxAmount}{ts}Tax Amount{/ts}{/capture}\n{/if}\n{capture assign=ts_total}{ts}Total{/ts}{/capture}\n{$ts_item|string_format:\"%-30s\"} {$ts_qty|string_format:\"%5s\"} {$ts_each|string_format:\"%10s\"} {if $dataArray} {$ts_subtotal|string_format:\"%10s\"} {$ts_taxRate} {$ts_taxAmount|string_format:\"%10s\"} {/if} {$ts_total|string_format:\"%10s\"}\n----------------------------------------------------------\n{foreach from=$value item=line}\n{capture assign=ts_item}{if $line.html_type eq \'Text\'}{$line.label}{else}{$line.field_ti
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems there are no templates which needs an update by civi on your site. To proceed you can try commenting [this part](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/MessageTemplates.php#L186-L190) from `CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/MessageTemplates.php` file.

I feel there should be an extra if condition added around this line to only execute the query if `$templatesToUpdate` is not an empty array value.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have successfully upgraded. I did get several messages - the first is below. I guess this means I did have templates needing upgrade and that they will never be upgraded. I can certainly live with that but just thought I'd ask if you have any thoughts. I know Eileen did a heap of work on this. Again many thanks Jitendra

Comment: Messages I received after upgrade - Three in all - this was just the first one.   
  "The default copies of the message templates listed below will be updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here for detailed instructions.Memberships - Receipt (on-line) - Use email greeting at top where available
    Contributions - Receipt (on-line) - Use email greeting at top where available
    Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (

Comment: OOPS sorry I just read message again and apparently the default copies did get upgraded -  I don't have any customized versions or does this refer to user-driven templates that are based on the system workflow messages?